# BusyBox date: retrieve date from the internet without ntpdate

Tags: shell, date, curl, busybox

Embedded poky linux, no `ntpdate` available.

It looks like none of the following commands is suitable:

```
# date -s "$(curl -s --head http://google.com | grep '^Date:' | cut -d' ' -f 3-)" 
date: invalid date '08 Mar 2021 13:22:34 GMT'
```

```
# date -s "$(curl -s --head http://google.com | grep '^Date:' | cut -d' ' -f 3-6)"
date: invalid date '08 Mar 2021 13:22:34'
```

```
#date +"%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S" -s "$(curl -s --head http://google.com | grep '^Date:' | cut -d' ' -f 3-6)"
date: invalid date '08 Mar 2021 13:22:34'
```

## UPDATE

BusyBox date only accepts the following date formats:

```
@seconds_since_1970
hh:mm[:ss]
[YYYY.]MM.DD-hh:mm[:ss]
YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm[:ss]
[[[[[YY]YY]MM]DD]hh]mm[.ss]
```

If the `-D` option is available in the BusyBox version you are using, you can use this command as suggested by [steeldriver](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/65304/steeldriver):

```
busybox date -d '08 Mar 2021 13:22:34' -D '%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S'
```

Comment: What is the `date` implementation on your system (GNU? `busybox`? something else?)

Comment: Yes, BusyBox v1.24.1

Comment: At least with my version of busybox (v1.27.2), the date command has a `-D` option for specifying the format of the `-d` datestring ex. `busybox date -d '08 Mar 2021 13:22:34' -D '%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S'` - not sure if that's available in v1.24.1?

Comment: Sadly not. If I run `busybox date -d '08 Mar 2021 13:22:34' -D '%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S'`, i get `date: invalid option -- 'D'`

Comment: I guess there's no simple way around hacking it with a script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I parsed the time string from google to put it in a `busybox date` friendly format (`YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS`). Hopefully someone will find this useful in the future.

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

monthnumber() {
    month=$1
    months="JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec"
    tmp=${months%%$month*}
    month=${#tmp}
    monthnumber=$((month/3+1))
    printf "%02d\n" $monthnumber
}

G_DATE="$(curl -s --head http://google.com | grep '^Date:' | cut -d' ' -f 3-6)"
G_SPLIT=($(echo $G_DATE | tr " "))

BB_DATE="${G_SPLIT[2]}-$(monthnumber ${G_SPLIT[1]})-${G_SPLIT[0]} ${G_SPLIT[3]}"

date -s "$BB_DATE"
```

`monthnumber()` function was taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/41385862/9815377

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could update busybox. I got V1.30 and the command works